# How can I add a caption to a photo in a shared Google Photos album?

Tags: google-photos

I have a collection of photos in a shared album on Google Photos. For each photo I want to set a short description as a caption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in either the [Google Photos app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&referrer=utm_source%3Dphotos_apps_page), or the [Google Photos website](https://photos.google.com/).

1. Tap or click to view a single photo, then select the information button (small "I" icon) to view more details on the photo.
2. Find and select "Add a Description"

Descriptions are saved with the image and will be searchable in the future.

Source: [How to add a custom description to pictures in Google Photos](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-add-custom-description-pictures-google-photos)